# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'subviews' is a get-only property

Tags: swift

```
for subview in self.subviews.reverse() //ERROR HERE
{
    let insideSubview = self.convertPoint(point, toView: subview)
    if let sview = subview.overlapHitTest(insideSubview, withEvent: event)
    {
        return sview
    }
}
```

I get the aforementioned error title there, how would I fix this?

Comment: Is `subviews` a variable? What is `subviews`? Can you show that?

Comment: @Rob, you can just do self.subviews ... it is not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reversed` rather than `reverse`. The former returns a new, reversed array. The latter attempts to mutate the existing array, which you don’t want in this case.

Thus:

```
for subview in subviews.reversed() { ... }
```

Comment: THANK YOU <3 ACCEPTING ANSWER WHEN I CAN